# Replacing one widget with another during run time and making the new widget show

Tags: c++, qt

I create a list of widgets that I store the pointers of these widgets to in a QList. I then have push buttons on the main widget that the user can use to cycle thru the list of widgets.

I use this code to replace the existing widget:

```
Shape* newShape = shapeList->moveNext();
newShape->draw();
mainLayout->addWidget(newShape, 1, 0);
update();
```

This code is in the SLOT connected to the push button's clicked signal. This code:

```
shapeList->moveNext();
```

Works and an existing already-added-to-list widget is returned. I am just not seeing the the changes on the ui???

Is there any special code needed to make this new widget replace the existing one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you using `QStackedLayout`. All you need to do is - add all your widgets to it and then just change current widget.

[Help article.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstackedlayout.html)